# Shortest distance between two general curves

Tags: calculus

Have to find shortest distance between
$$f(x)=-0.000024729x^7+0.0011461x^6-0.019857x^5+0.15402x^4-0.46314x^3-0,068261x^2+2.2506x-8.3436$$
and
$$g(x)=0.000016282x^8-0.00094728x^7+0.022526x^6-0.28122x^5+1.9699x^4-7.6833x^3+15.691x^2-14.557x+0.22000$$

I need all the help I can get! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Write the Euclidean distance (squared) as $((x_1,f(x_1)) - (x_2, g(x_2)))^2$.  Now you have a straightforward optimization in two variables, where you take derivatives, set to zero, ...

Here's a graph of your two functions:

[image]

where I've added the minimizing points (and joining line)... read on...

Pick an arbitrary point $x_1$ on $f(x)$ and another point $x_2$ on $g(x)$.  Draw a line between them.  That's the distance between those two points.  Right?

This Euclidean distance is a function of the two variables.  Since you tagged your question with "calculus" you surely must know how to find the (local) minimum of a function of two variables.

Apply that to your distance function.  (Actually, do it for the *square* of the distance function... simpler.)

You'll get many local minima and maxima, but the graphs will guide you to finding the global minimum.  (Also, you can use second-order derivatives.)

Here's a "closeup" of the solution:

[image]

Comment: I know i sound stupid but could you literally "spell it out"
Or show me? i'm completely blank

Comment: @Magnus do you know how to take a derivative of a function? If yes, then do you know about partial derivatives. You two equations that you need to solve in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$ are $$ \begin{aligned} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}& =0  \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} & =0 \end{aligned}$$ where $f = f(x_1,x_2)$ is the distance function mentioned above.